# Determining changing values of C in RC circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, impedance, frequency-measurement

My problem is related to the change in the membrane capacitance of a cell ([link to paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms1742)). The electrical properties of the cell can be modeled using a battery, a resistor and a capacitor in series.

I apply a sinusoidal wave (5 kHz, 10 mV amplitude)

During the process I apply an external stimulus that changes the capacitance of the system. This can be infrared light or anything that generates a pulse of heat.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fELpjw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The results I get for 1 trace is the following

[image: 1 sweep]

If I repeat this several times I get something like this

[image: 96sweeps]

I would like to know how the applied stimulus changes the capacitance in time?. 
My guess is that I could obtain the instantaneous phase shift and amplitudes from the several traces I have but I don't know how to do that.

The data can be found in the following files:
[Applied voltage](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-9SxXai27Zt1R9a9fmlEFmzKvJXwhnc_/view?usp=sharing)
[Current response](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j_Kh_k351Voysqpg8er9hC_SgFb5QQKY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Define each part. Ceramic parts decrease with DC bias voltage.

Comment: It`s a biological sample that can be described by electrical components.

Comment: Diodes also have a 0V maximum capacitance that declines with reverse bias. Precision ones are called Varicaps.  You can define it by some k/V ratio

Comment: The capacitance doesn't change - how did you conclude that from the results shown?

Comment: @Andyaka As I mentioned this is a biological system. You can get more details here https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms1742

Comment: @BPinto I read the article and their setup doesn't appear to replicate theirs, though I admit you don't write enough about it and while they write a lot I'm not sure it's enough that I could replicate it. I'd probably have to contact the authors to get more detail. While I do see them claim 'capacitance' because they claim that the current response tracked rate of temperature change, they didn't do a good job illustrating the data that leads to that conclusion and their charts merely show a capacitance axis, without support I can find for how they computed it.

Comment: @BPinto Other charts made me think otherwise, by the way. I think this is a poor paper, frankly. And I read peer-reviewed science papers on a daily basis. (Which proves nothing at all about my interpretation here except that I'm not completely unfamiliar with reading such papers and I'm willing to express an ignorant opinion about this one -- which I probably shouldn't do, but I'm just talking here so no harm done, really.) Can you walk me through that paper and show me which curves to examine, where I might adduce the capacitance they claim?

Comment: @jonk My setup is different but the idea behind is the same. How can I measure a changing capacitance using a sinusoidal waveform.  If you only have a capacitor (bilayer case in the paper) you can convert the changes in amplitude directly into changes in the capacitance (figure 3 D & F).

Comment: @BPinto I don't agree their paper demonstrates their claim. Their words make the claim you say they do. But I don't see the support for it and what I do see suggests to my ignorant eyes a somewhat different interpretation. So this means I am missing something (because, given the choice between me being unable to read the work well and the authors being unable to analyze their own work well, I would tend to go to the "I'm just ignorant" side of things.) I don't follow their work. And I feel I need to understand in order to be able to think for myself about helping. So I have to bow out.

Comment: Dear @jonk in biophysics a lipid bilayer works as a capacitor (a low dielectric medium composed of lipids). If you apply a voltage trough this bilayer it wil store charge Q=CV. If you apply a sinusoidal voltage the impedance will be given by this capacitor (you will have a 90 degrees shift in current and the magnitude of the impedance will be given by 1/sC). Now if you change the membrane capacitance you can guess how the impedance and then the current measured will change.

Comment: @BPinto I remember reading Dr. James E Lovelock's early work with lipids. What you wrote, makes sense. But I often find better answers by working backwards far before anything gets turned into an electronic signal and forwards after the last moment when an electronic signal is converted to some other physical parameter. Your use of an idealized electronics analogy as being entirely descriptive of a lipid system, tells me immediately I've learned nothing by listening to the analogy. I don't mean to badger. It's just that I don't feel I can given any good advice.

Comment: @BPinto I believe that you intentionally have no phase relationship with the applied sine wave and the applied pulse and that this is why your last image is almost entirely blacked out. It's just the bottoms and tops of the waves super-imposed with random phase relationships, that create the "shapes" that make up the top edge and the bottom edge, which I believe you feel carries the important information.

Comment: @BPinto But there are so many interesting aspects to those shapes, both at top and bottom and with respect to each other, and questions I'd like to discuss with you. This means I'd need to understand the lipid system much more than I do. And I can tell you one thing for certain from what I see in that last picture you included; this is NOT entirely described as the simpler system you've pushed in your question. I can see enough in that diagram to be almost certain of that. So I know I really can't help. It would just be my own ignorance pretending to be more. Better I say nothing.

Comment: @jonk this can be simulated by the system I just described. I and others have done simulations of this system and you get the same kind of response when you change make a quick change in the capacitor.

Comment: @BPinto I'm sure others agree with themselves and you. That happens all too often and can stagnate progress or it may be that it really is that way and that there's been time for a full consensus to properly develop, too, with sufficient affirming evidence and many different people from varying perspectives having weighed in with a comprehensive view to the available experimental result. But I see things in what you showed that require explanation beyond what I've seen written (in my opinion.) Don't get me wrong, though. I'm only saying I don't think I can be helpful. Not that you are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

All right, I'll take a stab at this. I don't know the science behind your study, but assuming that your circuit model is correct, we can solve this just by looking at the current \$i_1(t)\$ through AM1.

Call the voltages at the positive nodes of R1, C1, and V1 as \$V_1(t)\$, \$V_2(t)\$, and \$V_3(t)\$ respectively.

Using characteristic equations for the capacitor and resistor:

\$i_1(t) = C(t) \frac{d}{dt}(V_2(t) - V_1(t)) + (V_2(t) - V_1(t))*\frac{dC(t)}{dt} = V_1(t)/R1\$

EDIT: Thanks @Bpinto for noting the correct capacitor equation for time-varying capacitance.

And noting that \$V_2(t) = V_3(t) - 140 mV =  V_{applied}(t) - 140 mV\$, we find:

\$C(t) \frac{d}{dt}((V_{applied}(t) - 140 mV) - V_1(t)) + ((V_{applied}(t) - 140 mV) - V_1(t))*\frac{dC(t)}{dt} = V_1(t)/R1\$

But \$\frac{d}{dt}(140 mV) = 0\$ and \$V_1(t) = R1*i_1(t)\$, so:

\$C(t) \frac{d}{dt}(V_{applied}(t)) - \frac{di_1(t)}{dt} + ((V_{applied}(t) - 140 mV) - R1 * i_1(t))*\frac{dC(t)}{dt} = i_1(t)\$

Since all other terms are known, this reduces to a linear differential equation for \$C(t)\$:

\$[(V_{applied}(t) - 140 mV) - R1 * i_1(t)]\frac{dC(t)}{dt} + [\frac{d}{dt}(V_{applied}(t))] C(t) = i_1(t) + \frac{di_1(t)}{dt}\$

Comment: In this case the equation for a capacitor i = C dV/dT does not stand. Since Q=C*V the current dQ/dt = C * dV/dt + V dC/dt. Note that we added a new term because the capacitance is changing.

Comment: Thanks! Calculations updated.

Comment: Is it possible to consider  the sinusoidal time course? If we consider Vaapplied = sin(wt), this  would make dV/dt  = cosin(wt). I understand your solution is general, I was just considering if anny special relation would arise if we consider the specific wavefor.

Comment: @BPinto yep! Whatever your Vapplied(t) is, you can just plug it into the formula and take its derivative. One small correction: d/dt(sin(wt)) = w*cos(wt), not cos(wt) due to the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of accuracy you're looking for, but the capacitor in that circuit will charge up to 140mVDC.  When the capacitance changes, the charge on the cap will not change instantly, so the DC voltage will change by an amount proportional to the change in capacitance (reduced when the capacitance increases).  Of course, it will immediately begin to charge up to the 140mV value based on the new value of capacitance.  An external resistor much larger than the one in the model will help you measure that change from outside the black box.

In order to get a reference measure, though, amplitude and phase should work.  Remember that the voltage across the resistor is in phase with the current, and the voltage across the cap is 90 degrees out of phase with the current.  The vector sum of those two voltages (eliminating the 140mVDC) is the applied voltage.  From there you can determine both values.

Answer (score 0):

Ic= CdV/dt + VdC/dt  and capacitance can be polar or not yet  DC bias dependent, temperature dependent and many other variables that chanbge with excitation frequency.

In my opinion* this is a poor test and needs a network analyzer or FFT pulse analyzer from 0.1Hz to 10kHz with bias from DC, heat, cold.

- as a Test Engineer with 45 yrs experience ( and R&D )

Comment: Could you please elaborate?